# git add on a file excluded by .gitignore

Tags: git

Is there a way to track a new file in git that is excluded by a rule present in .gitignore? I would like to do this without adding a single file/directory exclusion in my .gitignore rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I was having a tough time finding an answer to this, but to be honest I hadn't tried it yet. Turns out running 'git add' (like below) on a file excluded in .gitignore

```
git add Test.exe
```

outputs the following:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
Test.exe
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

So revising 'git add' like so will work:

```
git add -f Test.exe
```

Comment: I think that editing `.gitignore` would be better. You can un-ignore file by adding `!Test.exe` to `.gitignore`. But it is your repository - your rules :)

Comment: It's an extra step I'd have to take. I already have enough crap I have to type in to commit my changes haha

Comment: Now, if this were to become a regular pattern with a specific subset of files, then yeah editing my .gitignore file would be the way to go. Like we have a "Tools" directory with a bunch of EXEs and MSIs in it, so I just have !Tools/**/*.msi and !Tools/**/*.exe since I'm always adding stuff to it.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Use -f if you really want to add them.
> ```

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), this is now an "hint", controlled with two new help messages given when "`git add`" notices the user gave it nothing to add.

That means, make sure `git config advice.addIgnoredFile` is not set to `true` (which is indeed the case by default: its default value is `false`), or you would not realize a `git add -f` is needed here.

See [commit 887a0fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/887a0fd57336dc5ff3ac28b6de0be91278e9e179) (06 Feb 2020), and [commit bf66db3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf66db37f1e17b71e8edb93d78ec407fbc1e0989) (07 Jan 2020) by [Heba Waly (`HebaWaly`)](https://github.com/HebaWaly).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit daef1b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/daef1b300b07c3d17d47c3bf01ebde28b62ff3fe), 14 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`add`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/887a0fd57336dc5ff3ac28b6de0be91278e9e179): change advice config variables used by the add API
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Heba Waly</sup>
>
> **`advice.addNothing`** config variable is used to control the visibility of two advice messages in the add library.
>   This config variable is replaced by **[two new variables](https://github.com/git/git/blob/887a0fd57336dc5ff3ac28b6de0be91278e9e179/Documentation/config/advice.txt#L113-L118)**, whose names are more clear and relevant to the two cases.
>
> Also add the two new variables to the documentation.
>
> - `addIgnoredFile`:
>     Advice shown if a user attempts to add an ignored file to the index.
> - `addEmptyPathspec`:
>     Advice shown if a user runs the add command without providing the pathspec parameter.

The hints now are:

```
Use -f if you really want to add them.
Turn this message off by running
"git config advice.addIgnoredFile false"
```

And:

```
Maybe you wanted to say 'git add .'?
Turn this message off by running
"git config advice.addEmptyPathspec false"
```